# vertical align bottom img and text using float

Tags: html, css

i am trying to align a block of text and an image on the same row using

```
display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;
```

this works but as soon as i float the span to the right, the vertical align stops working
can anyone lend a hand please
i am trying to align text to the bottom and float the blue span to the right
heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/YpVnw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a width to the containing div:

```
.mcone{ height:416px; width: 530px; float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/YpVnw/5/

I set `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You are inconsistent in what type of display you are using.  For the "wrapper" div, you're using a display:block; and then for the inner content (img, span), you're using display:table-cell (without having specified table-row for the parent div, and display:table for the parent div of the table-row)

Try this:

```
<div id="table">
        <div id="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <img src="http://beta.images.theglobeandmail.com/archive/01397/web-verizon_jpg_1397343cl-8.jpg" alt="" width="412" height="416" class="valign-middle"/>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell valign-bottom bgcolor">
                <span class='georgia'> Tkquis, dignissim sit amet erat. Cras quis diam s leo vel urna dignissim blandit. Ut ultrices, turpis dolor&nbsp; ntum nulla, eget euismod nisi met, eget euismod nisi metus sit amet nisl. Cu amet nisl. asdCum vitae nisi interdum elit sagittis vestibsulum. volutpat por ttitor. Vestibulum interdum, dolor eget ultridfadfsces ultrices,er turpis m vitae nisi interdum </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

#table { display: table; }
#table-row { display: table-row; }
.table-cell { display: table-cell; }
.valign-bottom { vertical-align: bottom; }
.valign-middle { vertical-align: middle; }
.bgcolor { background-color: #00CCCC; }
```

[image]